# Проблема с получением и проверки хеш-значения пароля

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, django, backend

У меня есть функция,которая обрабатывает данные полученные с помощью POST-метода. На вход приходят пароль и логин,если данных пользователя нет в БД то они записываются,если есть,то должно вернуть соответствующее сообщение.

```
def create(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    password = (request.POST.get("password")).encode()
    users = UserInfo.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        if user.login == request.POST.get("login"):
            if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user.password) == user.password:#В данном месте ошибка
                return HttpResponse("<h1>Person exist</h1>")
    user = UserInfo()# Если в БД нету данного пользователя
    user.login = request.POST.get("login")
    hash_pasword = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
    user.password = hash_pasword
    user.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

С записью в БД все в порядке,но вот когда нужно проверить значения на наличие их в БД происходит ошибка

```
 File "E:\Projects\CourseWork\application\views.py", line 16, in create
    if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user.password) == user.password:#В данном месте ошибка
  File "C:\Users\bogda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 61, in hashpw
    raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing")
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Предпологаю,что ошибка происходит при возвращении хеш-значения из БД,возможно что-то с типом данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
password = request.POST.get("password").encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: ошибка в данном куске кода
`if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user.password) == user.password:`